# Replacement of a substring with another substring in a string

Tags: strings

I apologize if this is not the right stackexchange for this question. I was playing around with the Python programming language, when I discovered something strange. It concerns replacing a substring of a string with another substring. For example, in "spammy", replacing "mm" with "xx" results in "spaxxy". However, in "spammmy", replacing "mm" with "xx" results in "spaxxmy", not "spaxxxxy" or even "spaxxxy". My question is, what is the proper, rigorous definition of replacing in a string $S$ a substring $T$ with a substring $T'$?

Answer (score 1):

There is no proper, rigorous definition.  Or, rather, you can make multiple definitions.  All are valid.  You could provide a rigorous definition for replacing the first match, or a rigorous definition for replacing all matches.  Mathematics doesn't tell you which definition is "proper" or "best" or "most useful".

A meta-comment: You might to be expecting more from mathematics than it can bear.  Mathematics doesn't tell you what is "proper" or "right" or "best".  It gives us a model for a world: if the structure satisfies such-and-such conditions, then it has such-and-such properties.  You'll have to decide what conditions are appropriate, or what properties you want to have.